# Choosing right representation of entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have Album model:

```
public class Album
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Track> Tracklist { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to implement functionality of adding new album into database in the next way:

1. On the first view user should see form with fields "Artist" and "Album name".
2. Then he posts this fields to action, which should send album.getInfo request to Lastfm API (http://www.lastfm.ru/api/show/album.getInfo).
3. New album should be constructed from response and passed to user. He should be able to check correctness of received information and edit any field, if necessary.
4. Then he posts entire album to action, which saves it to db.

How you would implement this scenario? In particular, it's better to pass one model (Album) to every action, or to create models for every action (two, in that case)? Same question about actions and views: it's better to perform all user interactions regarding creating and editing album in one action and view, or to separate them somehow?

I have several workarounds, but all they seem to me not very elegant, and I feel, there should be better solution.

Comment: Use one model per context(i.e more than one Album model for everything) then map between models if required. Btw, DRY has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this scenario with AJAX. Not only will it be better for the user (no round-trips required), but it also makes it just a standard old form submission server-side (in other words, very easy). Basically, you'd just have your standard GET and POST actions:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Album();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Album model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Albums.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges()
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@model Namespace.To.Album


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Artist)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Artist)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)

    <div class="js-visible">
        <button type="button" id="LookupAlbum">Lookup</button>
    </div>

    <div id="AlbumFields" class="js-hidden">
        <!-- rest of the fields here -->
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Create</button>
}
```

The classes, `js-visible` and `js-hidden` are convenience classes that I like to use. Their implementation is very simple, and even simpler if you're using something like Modernizr, as it will add a `js` class to your `html` element if JavaScript is supported and enabled.

**With Modernizr**

CSS

```
.js-visible {
    display:none;
}
.js js-visible {
    display:block;
}

.js .js-hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**Without Modernizr**

CSS

```
.js-visible {
    display:none;
}
```

JS (actually jQuery to not belabor the code sample)

```
$('.js-visible').show();
$('.js-hidden').hide();
```

Anyways, the idea here is that if there's no JavaScript capability or it's been disabled, the lookup button won't display and instead, the user will just see all the fields. However if you can use JavaScript (and hence do the AJAX lookup), then the remaining album fields will be initially hidden and the lookup button will appear after the first two fields.

Then, you just need the some JavaScript to handle your lookup:

```
 $('#LookupAlbum').on('click', function () {
     var artist = $('#Artist').val();
     var album = $('#Name').val();

     $.get('/some/url', { artist: artist, album: album }, function (result) {
         // fill in the remaining fields with retrieved information
         $('#LookupAlbum').hide();
         $('#AlbumFields').show();
     });
 });
```

I intentionally tried to keep this code basic, because a lot of what happens with the AJAX call is dependent upon what you're doing. The URL will either be directly to LastFM if their API supports JSONP (in which case, the body of your AJAX call will be different and you'll need to implement a callback function to be called by the JSONP that will fill in your fields. If LastFM doesn't offer JSONP or you just don't want to do it that way, then the URL would go to an action you would create that would call the LastFM API and return it's response (basically just creating a proxy to get around the same-origin restriction).

Long and short, you get the info from the API asynchronously and fill in the fields via JavaScript. Then, hide the lookup button and show the remaining album fields. The user can now fill in anything that's left or modify what LastFM returned and submit just once.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer! I thought about AJAX, but intentionally tried to implement this scenario without it in order to understand ASP.NET MVC concepts better.